# What to embed for a Richview Textbox with some formatting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, richtextbox

I have a webpage which has a textbox section in it. I want it to be similar like this image:
[image]

But not that much complicated regarding code files goes. Want the user to edit some characters put some Bold/Underline/Italic fonts into it. Some smileys that all.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many great open source controls that do this free and easily.  If you're using MVC, I recommend [tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/), or if you're using webforms, [FreeTextBox](http://www.freetextbox.com/) is great.